# Solving a log equation with squared bases

Tags: logarithms

I need to solve the equation below for x

$$ \log_a x = log_{a^2}(x+6) $$
Note that the base a itself is squared in the RHS of the equation

I've thought about tackling the LHS and RHS separately and end up with a quadratic with two solutions of x, one of which is negative, which can't be right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$\log_ax=\log_{a^2}(x+6)=k$(say)

$a^k=x,x+6=(a^2)^k=(a^k)^2=x^2$

Remember, for real analysis, we need $x,x+6>0$ assuming $a>0$

Comment: Ok it looks like my method was right, I did get two solutions of -2 and 3, but thought that both had to be valid, instead of rejecting the -2 solution

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{ln(x)}{\ln(a)}=\frac{\ln(x+6)}{\ln(a^2}$$ for $$a>0$$ and $a\neq 1$ we get
$$2\ln(x)=\ln(x+6)$$ threrefore $$x^2=x+6$$
can you solve this?

Comment: Yep, I got there by another way, but because I had two solutions, one of which was negative, I thought the whole answer was wrong instead of just rejecting that negative solution

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\log_{a^2}(x+6)=\frac{\log_{a}(x+6)}{\log_a(a^2)}=\frac{\log_{a}(x+6)}{2}$.

Can you proceed ?